# Multiple datasource config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource

I work on a project witch contains two dataSources.
If I want to inject the securityDataSource, spring injects the defaultDataSource instead.

applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="defaultDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${default.jndi.datasource.name}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>${security.jndi.datasource.name}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

setter :

```
@Required
@Resource
public void setSecurityDataSource(DataSource securityDataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(securityDataSource);
}
```

The server logs this (which apparently isn't blocking anything though) for both security and default datasource:

```
10:28:23.912 [INFO ] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'defaultDataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:28:24.345 [INFO ] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'defaultDataSource' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:28:24.922 [INFO ] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'securityDataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10:28:25.444 [INFO ] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'securityDataSource' of type [class org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

No stacktrace is shown anywhere in the code.

When I try :

```
private SecurityUserDTO retrieve(String userLogin) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", with(userLogin), new UserExtractor());
}
```

Hibernate wont find the table users stored in database security, because it looks for it in the default database (which doesn't have such a table)

```
HTTP Status 401 - PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'condor.users' doesn't exist
```

if I try injecting and providing the name securityDataSource:

```
@Required
@Resource(name="securityDataSource")
public void setSecurityDataSource(DataSource securityDataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(securityDataSource);
}
```

I will get a stackTrace :

```
12:17:48.557 [ERROR] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'securityDataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:159) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303) ~[spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
Wrapped by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'securityDataSource' is defined
```

However, the bean securityDataSource exists indeed, and was instanciated by spring in the context.

help me please, thanks !

Comment: Make sure that you have only one spring context at runtime (and so all your beans goes to it). The problem may be that you have multiple contexts. Your datasources are declared in one and injected in another. Example of the situation when you have two contexts: if you use Spring MVC then you normally have one context for application beans (services, DAOs, etc.) and another one for Spring MVC controllers.

Comment: Any idea why you are seeing two entries each with the "BeanPostProcessors" warning? I would have expected to only see the JndiObjectFactoryBean line and not the BasicDataSource lines. Also, are you able to get the app to work with only one of either entry, but not both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my defaultDataSource bean was declared in applicationContext.xml whereas my securityDataSource bean was in applicationContext-security.xml, although not declared to be browsed in the web.xml by the contextConfigLocation. 
Here is the sample code that was changed:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and it works !
The securityDataSource bean that I had seen belonged to another context...